# Mapping Shift + Escape to ~ From the Command Line

Tags: command-line, keyboard-shortcuts

I own a 60% keyboard that does not have a <kbd>~</kbd> key. Before when I was on MacOS, I used to use [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) to map <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to <kbd>~</kbd>.

Now that I've switched to Linux, I would like to know how I can do the same on Linux with just terminal commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `X11`

```
xmodmap -e 'keysym Escape = Escape asciitilde Escape'
```

Would map `~` to Shift + any key that is currently mapped to Escape.

Comment: Works like a charm!